# How to change the source data of an Excel pivot table

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, excel, vba

**Aim to achieve :**
I want to change the source data for my pivot table in Excel using VB.Net to a named range.

I have :

```
table.ChangePivotCache(wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=sheet.Names("name_of_NamedRange").RefersToRange))
```

**Exception :**

```
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SourceData needs to be a string that contains the address, including the sheet name, like 'My Sheet'!A1:B10.  Try this:

```
table.ChangePivotCache(wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=sheet.Names("name_of_NamedRange").RefersToRange.Address(External:=True)))
```

Comment: But that will give `Data connections disabled` warning in Excel sheet.. The source data is in the same file.. `External:=True` will also have the file name in the address.

Comment: The "Data connections disabled" warning sounds like a separate issue.  I understand about the source data being in the same workbook.  In my testing Excel resolved the source correctly - sheet name but not workbook name, using the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `sheet.Names("name_of_NamedRange").Value` refers to a Range?

Comment: I think you are right.. But I used `.RefersToRange` instead of `.Value` but still the error remains the same.